# How to fix ESLint 'no-param-reassign' without configuring the rules?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I want to use ESLint on my React app.

Here is some of my code:

```
export const getParamValues = (url) => {
  return url
    .slice(1)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((prev, curr) => {
      const [title, value] = curr.split('=');
      prev[title] = value;
      return prev;
    }, {});
};
```

How can I pass 'no-param-reassign' without configuring the rules?

Is there any possibility to change only my code to pass the linting?

Comment: You're breaking that rule by mutating `prev`. If you want to change the _code_, rather than the config, you'd have to return a new object from that callback instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the warning and instead of mutating treat it as immutable:

```
const [title, value] = curr.split('=');
return {...prev, [title]: value};
```